# Convert double of null value to String Error

Tags: java

How to solve this problem

```
public class DoubleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double dbl = (Double) null;
        String str = Double.toString(dbl);
        System.out.println(str);

    }

}
```

With Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.java.DoubleTest.main(DoubleTest.java:6)
```

Any idea please?

I am asking this because I have a method that return Double which I have to convert to String again.

If my method returns **null**, then this problem happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a method returning null like this:

```
Double d = myMethod();
```

Then you can have Double to String conversion like this:

```
String str = "";

if (d != null)
   str = d.toString();
```

Answer (score 6):

This will always fail:

```
 double dbl = (Double) null;
```

You can't assign null to a primitive (lower case double).
If you change it to an upper case Double, the assignment will work, but then Double.toString(dbl) fails, since it can't take a null.  To prevent this, you can then change your code to something like was suggested before (assuming db1 is a Double and not a double):

```
String str = dbl != null ? Double.toString(dbl) : "null";
```

This will always print "null" since db1 will always be null.

Comment: @Mawia Nope. You can't store a `null` in a `double`.

Comment: Actually, the above code will compile, but fail with a Nullpointerexception due to the cast. If you remove the cast to double the compiler will catch the assignment of the primitive to null...

Answer (score 3):

[`From JLS #5.1.8. Unboxing Conversion`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)

- If r is a reference of type `Double`, then unboxing conversion converts
  r into `r.doubleValue()`
- If r is `null`, unboxing conversion throws a `NullPointerException`

Here is the byte code generated for your program

```
 0  aconst_null
 1  invokevirtual java.lang.Double.doubleValue() : double [16]
 4  dstore_1 [dbl]
 5  dload_1 [dbl]
 6  invokestatic java.lang.Double.toString(double) : java.lang.String [22]
 9  astore_3 [str]
10  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [26]
13  aload_3 [str]
14  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String) : void [32]
17  return
```

A proper solution for this would involve using of `String.valueOf` which already handles `null` case.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double dbl = null;
    String str = String.valueOf(dbl);//Str will have `null` value
    System.out.println(str);

}
```

Second approach

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double dbl = null;
    String str = null;
    if (dbl != null) {
        str = String.valueOf(dbl);// <--This is dead code currently but it
                                    // is useful if you are checking
                                    // against null
    }
    System.out.println(str);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 double dbl = (Double) null;
```

is the problem here, but it's actually related to the cast from null to Double. You will get a `Nullpointerexception` due to the cast here, not because of the assignment.

A similar issue would arise from Autounboxing an Object to a primitive where the Object is null:

```
Double myDouble = null;
double dbl = myDouble;
```

Answer (score 0):

Double has a toString method which should ideally take care of the conversion itself.

Since Double can also be null, you might want to handle it yourself or let the toString return it as "null".

`String str = (dblVariable == null)? {custom-code-here} : dblVariable.toString();`